# Mongo / Mongoose: Does Mongoose automatically create indexes on ObjectId types?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I may have missed this in the mongo index documentation or in the mongoose documentation.

Suppose I have a mongoose schema as such:

```
const SomeEntity = new Schema({
  foo:  { type: String, required: true },
  bar   { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Bar' }
});
```

Should I be creating an index on field `bar` or would mongo automatically address this?

In other words, does mongo automatically create indexes for ObjectId types ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> In other words, does mongo automatically create indexes for ObjectId types ?

No, the only automatic index that MongoDB creates [is for the `_id` field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#default-id-index).

However, it depends on the type of queries you're going to run against your model if you need an index for `bar`.

Since `bar` refers to the `_id` field of documents in the `bars` collection, those documents themselves will be covered by the automatic `_id` index that will get created on that collection.

But if you need to be able to find documents in the "SomeEntity" collection that refer to a specific bar:

```
SomeEntity.find({ bar : someBarId })
```

...then you probably want to create an index for it:

```
bar: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Bar', index : true }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, the latter is exactly what I need.